# WPF application throws an 'XmlParseException was unhandled' when using Converter

Tags: wpf, image, converters

I am building a small Wpf aplication to learn myself wpf.
And i have encountered a problem with one of the controlers.
i Have an object with a list of url's in a string format, and i want to bind them to an image and use the wpf converter class to convert the url's to bitmaps.

But when i implement the converter the program throws the following error:

> **'XmlParseException was unhandled'**

And in the details it says this:

> "{"Unable to cast object of type
>   'ChanGrabber.Converter' to type
>   'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'."}"

This is the code for referencing the converter in the xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChanGrabber">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Converter x:Key="Convert"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is the code where i use the control:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{Binding ThumbImgUrl, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and here is the code for the converter:

```
namespace ChanGrabber
{
    class Converter
    {
        [valueconversion(typeof(string), typeof(bitmapimage))]
        public class imageconverter : ivalueconverter
        {
            public object convert(object value, type targettype, object parameter, system.globalization.cultureinfo culture)
            {
                try
                {
                    string mypath = (string)value;
                    uri myuri = new uri(mypath);
                    bitmapimage animage = new bitmapimage(myuri);
                    return animage;
                }
                catch (exception)
                {

                    return new bitmapimage(new uri("ikke funket"));
                }
            }

            public object convertback(object value, type targettype, object parameter, system.globalization.cultureinfo culture)
            {
                throw new notimplementedexception();
            }
        }
```

And this is is the object i am binding to the image

```
class MainPosts : MainLinks
    {
        public MainPosts(string _title, string _link, String _postText, string _imageUrl, string _thumbUrl) :base(_title,_link)
        {
            PostText = _postText;
            ImageUrl = _imageUrl;
            ThumbImgUrl = _thumbUrl;
        }

        public String PostText { get; set; }

        public String ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string ThumbImgUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

I have no idea why it won't work, and i am getting abit frustrated on the program.
Any help will be so incredibly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

use  `<local:imageconverter x:Key="Convert"/>`

Comment: Thanks, that helped.
Turns out the problem was that i had put the imageconverter class inside another class called converter.
But i was to code-blind to see it.
Your suggestion put me on the track to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your converter needs to implement the `IValueConverter` interface, otherwise WPF won't know what to do with it (so it gives you that exception.)

```
class Converter : IValueConverter
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that wasn't the problem.
I had somehow managed to press the keycombination that made everything small caps when i copied the code.